# sum() on a relations relation in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, orm, eloquent, relation

I want to sum the persons score with Eloquent ORM. How do i do that in Laravel 4 with these relations?

[image: The relation-tree]

In my mind i would do something like that, but it isn't possible when using one-to-many-relations.

```
$person->attributes()->values()->scores()->sum("score");
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Sorry for me probably not being helpful, but I'm curious, why it isn't possible? It seems to me it should work, if you have relations defined properly on your models.

Comment: Hi @StasMakarov ! :)
Because my relations is one-to-many.

Answer (score -1):

Dont use eager loading, its slow. Do it with join 
`Person::with(['attributes.values.scores']);`
and why scores have many persons?
Use foreach, or custom query after scores

Comment: Laravel will automatically do the first 2 relationships for you when you do attributes.values.scores :)